# Why are many 9V DC wall adapter power supply measured as 12-14V by a multimeter?

Tags: power-supply, power, transformer, dc, rectifier

I have tried with many (working) 230V - 9V DC wall adapter power supply (of different brands, some of them coming with an electronic Yamaha device, etc.):

- they all show a higher voltage when measured in "DC mode" by my multimeter, like 12V - 14V
- they even show a higher voltage when measuring in "AC mode" of the multimeter: ~ 30V! This doesn't really make sense: the output of the power supply should be DC, so a theoretic AC voltage should be 0V. Ok, I understand the output of such an adapter is never "perfectly" DC, and there might still be a small sinusoidal component... However, why 30V?

**What could be the reason of this higher than normal voltage?**

Could it be a ripple after the [rectifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier)?

PS: I don't own a oscilloscope to test the output of the wall adapter, but I will try to borrow one!

PS2: if it was only with 1 such adapter, it could just be a faulty one. But now I've tested about 6 different (working) adapters of different brands...

PS3: it's a cheap multimeter ([link](https://www.amazon.fr/dp/B01EV44V5A/ref=pe_3044141_189395771_TE_dp_1)) but efficient. All other voltages that I measured have always been correct.

Comment: These are probably unregulated supplies.  Products designed to use one of these specifically take that into account. For a hobby project consider a switching supply almost implicitly with regulation.

Comment: Ripple + the fact that without a load their output will be higher (if its just the transformer + diode bridge + capacitor type)

Comment: A good tutorial here: [Hey! Why is my 9V wall-wart outputting 14V?!](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/103).